# Stack Overflow reputation and profile link in email sign

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, stack-snippets, signatures

I wonder if there is a Stack Overflow snippet to add my reputation and link to my profile to use as a signature for my email account. 
Does it make sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049569/kiks73/flair

Comment: you could go to your profile settings and use the flair

Comment: You must, of course, choose the Hotdog theme.

Comment: Hotdog theme is how You do it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use Flair.

Navigate to your profile -> "Edit Profile and Settings" -> Flair (under the Site Settings subheader). There you'll find an HTML snippet for a generated image with contains your profile picture, your username, your reputation and your badge count, either for a specific site:

[image: profile for Mureinik at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Or for the entire Stack Exchange network:

[image: profile for Mureinik on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: I'm just curious... this does not work with gmail, does it? (also, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627273/is-it-possible-to-render-html-in-gmail)

Comment: @lealceldeiro gmail supports HTML signatures, so I see no reason this shouldn't work (although I haven't tested it myself).

Comment: I've found some problems with gmail too. I had to insert the image from the URL in the snippet and set a link from the image to my profile. Coping & pasting flair code to gmail signature doesn't work.

Comment: @kiks73 this may be helpful to you: http://mydesignpad.com/how-to-install-html-email-signature-for-google-gmail/